# update column data into a table without removing the existing data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update one column data with the existing data but i don't want to remove previous record also. 
IF i do update query the previous record will delete.
I want both records in the same table.
Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
Table: transformation_target_metadata

For dataSetType = 'Knipper' table is already existed.I need to perform all the changes for dataSetType = 'Synergistixs'

datasetname     dataSetType    Name
Knipper         knipper        comma
Knipper         Knipper        VendorName
Knipper         Knipper        Brand

datasetname     dataSetType         Name
Knipper         Synergistixs        comma
Knipper         Synergistixs        VendorName
Knipper         Synergistixs        Brand
```

When i trigger the below query the output will come like this:

```
select * from transformation_target_metadata where datasetname in('Knipper') and dataSetType in('Knipper');

datasetname     dataSetType    Name
Knipper         knipper        comma
Knipper         Knipper        VendorName
Knipper         Knipper        Brand

select * from transformation_target_metadata where datasetname in('Knipper') and dataSetType in('Synergistixs');

datasetname     dataSetType         Name
Knipper         Synergistixs        comma
Knipper         Synergistixs        VendorName
Knipper         Synergistixs        Brand
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want `insert`:

```
insert into transformation_target_metadata (datasetname,     dataSetType, Name)
    select datasetname,  'Synergistixs', Name
    from transformation_target_metadata
    where dataSetType = 'Knipper';
```